# Facebook login inserts wrong id into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, authentication

I need to add facebook login to my website with double mechanism. First one fires when user click fb login, script checks whether fbid exists in my database and if true sets session. If fbid does not exist script picks up additional data like username and email and then insert fbid into DB. Problem is my code inserts wrong id into db if fbid doesn't exist. Here is my code:

```
 <?php
 require_once('lib/facebook.php');
  include "db.php";
$statara='';
  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxx',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
$fb_user='';
    if($user_id) {

      // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
      // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
      try {
        $fql = 'SELECT uid,name from user where uid = ' . $user_id;
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api(array(
                                   'method' => 'fql.query',
                                   'query' => $fql,
                                 ));

        // FQL queries return the results in an array, so we have
        //  to get the user's name from the first element in the array.

    }
       catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
        // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
        // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
        // just ask the user to login again here.
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
        $udj= 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login. redef</a>';
        error_log($e->getType());
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }   
    } else {

      // No user, so print a link for the user to login
      $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
     $udj= '<a href="' . $login_url . '" id="fblogin">login. redeff</a>';

    }

 if ($user_id){
        $sqlf=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where fbid='$user_id'");
        $sqlf_num=mysql_num_rows($sqlf);
    if ($sqlf_num > 0) { //// Users fbid exist put out his username from db
while($frow=mysql_fetch_array($sqlf)){
$username=$frow['username'];

$fb_user=$username;

}}else{ //// users fbid does not exist so insert him 
    $fb_user="$user_id to addd";
    $sqli=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(fbid) VALUES('$user_id')");
$stat= "<br><a href='logout.php'>logout ".$fb_user." </a><br>";
 }

} else{
 $stat="<br>not connected<br>";
 }
 echo "$udj $fb_user ";

?>
```

Comment: Seems to me (I could be wrong) that you're mixing PDO with `mysql_`

Comment: Question though. Why are you using `mysql_*` functions with this? They are deprecated, especially with Facebook.

Comment: i got used to them...so what should i change in my code to make it work ?? help pls

Comment: To be honest with you, I don't know. I'm not into Facebook apps. And why this line `$fb_user="$user_id to addd";`? is it pseudo code?

Comment: i just put it there to make it easier to get around...

Comment: so should i use mysqli then ??

Comment: Then why not just use a conditional statement to NOT enter anything in DB if the user doesn't exist? *"Problem is my code inserts wrong id into db if fbid doesn't exist."*

Comment: Yes, using `mysqli_*` functions with prepared statements or PDO would be better, and safer; for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic seems to be ok to fetch the user details using FQL. Now I see the section where you are adding the user into the DB

```
$fb_user="$user_id to addd"; // not sure what is this
$sqli=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(`fbid`) VALUES('".$user_id."')");
$stat= "<br><a href='logout.php'>logout ".$fb_user." </a><br>";
```

Can you try

```
$sqli=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(`fbid`) VALUES('".$user_id."')");
```

In addition you can debug by echoing the $user_id before doing the insert.

Also you can use graph api calls instead of FQL to get the user info as

```
$facebook->api('/me');
```

Comment: i get the same problem...my fbid is 100000084542137 and when i hit login it inserts this number 2147483647 ??

Comment: what is the fbid Data Type and length you gave in the table, make sure its bigint

Comment: Good I had the same issue earlier FB had smaller ids now past one year they have made it long and we went similar issues :)

Comment: `Another Happy Ending`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the fbid **column type** in your table from **INT** to **BIGINT**.
This worked for me.

Additional info, my BIGINT column type defaults to a length of 20.